# WebSocket over AF_UNIX socket

Tags: websocket, ipc, unix-socket

Is it possible to use `WebSocket` over `AF_UNIX` sockets (Unix-domain sockets)? Is it technically possible, and if so, do any implementations (mainly browser runtimes) support it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. [AutobahnPython](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython) supports running WebSocket over *any* stream-based transport supported by [Twisted](http://www.twistedmatrix.com/) like:

- TCP
- TLS
- Unix Domain Socket
- Pipes
- Serial

Please see [here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_endpoints).

FWIW, it also supports [tunneling](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/wrapping) *any* stream-based protocol over WebSocket. E.g. it allows you to run SSH over WebSocket (over any stream-based protocol).

As far as I know, no browser supports anything but TCP/TLS for WebSocket as underyling transport.

Comment: Do any browser runtimes (Gecko, WebKit etc) support this?

Comment: @el.pescado I don't know for sure, but I guess it's unlikely. However, here is a related discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.b2g/_0PaKyrUxFg